# How was my avatar retrieved?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

I've never been on this site, before. My company logo is, of course, public and available in many places. My blog logo is a variation. I just posted an 'answer' and was asked my name (I used my first name only), my email address (I gave a gmail address that I use) and my home page, for which I gave my blog. Yet, after posting, my company logo appeared immediately. How was that done? From where was my logo accessed. It's a pretty neat web programming trick, even if it is easily available, in a lot of places IMHO

Answer (score 8):

I think Stack Exchange retrieves logos from [Gravatar](http://www.gravatar.com/), based on your email address.

Comment: That it does. However it is possible it will retrieve from another service as well, such as twitter, et cettera. It's likely not the case for Ray here though. :)

Comment: If you view the source for the avatar images, you will see that they do indeed come from gravatar.com.

Answer (score 0):

Probably related to how he signed in via openid. This would be an off-topic or meta question though.